# How to RemoveAll from list where any object property is null or empty?

Tags: c#, linq, list, reflection

I have an object with many properties. I create a list of these objects and weed out the bad ones by finding cases where an important property is null or empty. Like...

```
theList.RemoveAll(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ID));
```

How can I do a similar check but instead of checking a single property, check if any property in the object IsNullOrEmpty?

I've been working with Reflection to get things like

```
object x = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties().
    Select(p => p.GetValue(exampleObject, null)).
    Where(v => string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.ToString())));
```

but I don't grock it well enough to put it all together. Please set me straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> check if any property in the object IsNullOrEmpty?

```
theList.RemoveAll(x => x.GetType().GetProperties()
                                  .Select(p => p.GetValue(x, null))
                                  .Any(p => p == null));
```

Comment: As a note the null in GetValue is where you would put an array specifying the indexes for indexed properties.  If there are any indexed properties for your object the code will throw anArgumentException if this is null.  Use PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters() if it returns an array with length 0 the property is not indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Thus it makes sense to apply `String.IsNullOrEmpty` only to string values, you should select only properties of string type:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
// fill list

var stringProperties = typeof(MyObject)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .ToArray();
```

And then get filtered sequence of objects:

```
var query = objects.Where(o =>
    stringProperties.All(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)p.GetValue(o))));
```

You can use same approach to remove objects from list:

```
objects.RemoveAll(o => 
     stringProperties.Any(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)p.GetValue(o))));
```

[**WORKING SAMPLE**](http://ideone.com/DyGPIT)